# Project renders with a huge square taking over the text

Tags: rendering, mesh, lighting, text-object

I am extremely new to Blender and was following a youtube tutorial for this project. The guy didn't go into a lot of details about rendering but his project rendered fine. However, mine has a huge square blocking most of the render

[image: Finished product]

I assumed it was an issue with the area lighting, so I got rid of all of it and just had the plain 3-d text. The box still shows up.

[image: Render with lighting removed]

Is there an issue with the mesh? I followed the tutorial to a tee and don't understand why this is happening.

Thank you for any input you may have!

Comment: Have a look to the outliner: the Cube object is hidden for the viewport, but not for rendering.

Comment: Click the camera icon beside the cube in the outliner to disable it when rendering. At the moment it's just hidden in the viewport but will still be rendered.